# Is finding the basis of the image the same thing as finding the image?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I know that a basis spans a vector space and all the vectors of the basis are linearly independent. The image is the span of all linear combinations. To find the image, put the matrix in rref. The columns in rref with leading 1's are linearly independent. The image of the matrix are the vectors in the original matrix that correspond with the leading 1's in rref.

I guess it's a question of terminology. If asked to find the image of a matrix, is it equivalent to say "find the basis of the image of a matrix?" And can the same be said about the kernel?

Comment: I would think so - once you have the column space you can find a basis, and conversely.

Comment: Exhibiting a basis is one of several ways to describe the image of a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if $T:V \to W$ is a linear map, then $\mathrm{Im}(T)$ is a subspace of $W$ and $\ker(T)$ ais a subspace of $V$. In particular,  they are closed under the vector space operations. Hence, if you find a *basis* for the corresponding subspaces, you have succeeded in fully describing them.

On the other hand, I think a generating set would do the job just fine. As in, if
$\ker T:=\{a_1v_1+\dots +a_nv_n \mid a_i \in \mathbb{F}, v_i \in V\}$ for some collection of $\{v_i\}$, then you have also described the kernel, although this description is suboptimal.